How to book a multi-city itinerary, using Qantas Business Rewards points, for multiple travellers
Does anyone know if it's possible to use Qantas Business Rewards points to book:

a multi-city itinerary, which is
for myself and family members?

If I log in to my Qantas Business Rewards account, there is an option to book a Return or One-Way flight. When I choose this option, the Select Travellers dropdown knows about me and my family members, and it knows how many Qantas Business Rewards points I have:

But when I choose the Multi-City option, it takes me to the standard multi-city page at https://www.qantas.com/.../book-a.../flights/multi-city.html, and asks me to log in again:

If I choose the Business Rewards Login option on this panel, it takes me back to the first page, so I can't use the Multi-City option.
If I log in using my personal Qantas Frequent Flyer number, it doesn't know anything about my Qantas Business Rewards points, or my other family members.
TLDR; how can I book a multi-city itinerary using my Qantas Business Rewards points?

You probably can't (at least not without calling customer service), but you probably also don't need to?
Qantas flight rewards points are calculated in terms of one-way fares, so the cost in points will be the same if you just book a series of one-way tickets instead of one multi-city ticket.  As a bonus, you'll also get much greater flexibility, since award availability is limited and it's unlikely you'll be able to get multiple seats on exactly the same flights for everybody in your itinerary.

great advice, thanks. The other tip I saw was to transfer the points from the Business account to each individual user's account in order to book the flights.
